# Get texts in table cells of column

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm new to Scrapy and am scraping Wikipedia websites like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_dishes) which have several tables.
My goal is to get all the text from the first column of each table,
appending each text to a list of strings.

Some text are part of a link.

For example [this table column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw4Hv.png). The first cell has a text inside anchor element "Double steaming" but also has text "/ double boiling".

I tried:

```
for table in response.css('.wikitable'):
    table.css('td:nth-child(1) ::text').get()
```

But this only gets first cell text of each table, not all column text:

```
'Double steaming'
```

Then tried using `getall`:

```
for table in response.css('.wikitable'):
    table.css("td:nth-child(1) ::text").getall()
```

but this gets all texts in the first column separately:

```
['Double steaming', ' / double boiling', 'Red cooking', 'Stir frying']
```

This is the output I want:

```
['Double steaming / double boiling', 'Red cooking', 'Stir frying']
```

How can I do this with Scrapy?

Comment: wikipedia does a nice job marking their tables. The easiest way to get all the tables from most wikipedia pages is with pandas. `table_list = pd.read_html(url)`, which creates a list of dataframes for each table.

Comment: `dfl = pd.read_html(url); strs = list(); for d in dfl[1:-4]: strs += d.iloc[:, 0].str.lower().to_list(); strs = set(strs)` split at the `;`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking to use Scrapy but I didn't know pandas could read HTML tables.

Comment: You're welcome. I figured, which is why I didn't put it as an answer. But it's often an easier solution for websites with the correct table tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tough to test without the specific page, but a solution I can think of is looping through each cell and joining the text.

```
for table in response.css('.wikitable'): 
    cells = table.css("td:nth-child(1)") 
    column_data = [] 
    for cell in cells:  
        data = "".join(cell.css('::text').getall())
        # could preform additional cleaning here
        column_data.append(data.strip()) 
    print(column_data)
```

`column_data` should be `['Double steaming / double boiling', 'Red cooking', 'Stir frying']` in theory

Comment: Thank you, I ran this in my code and it worked.